# Unable to create or return Reversed Linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

Here using the function `returnReverseLinkedList` I am returning the reversed linked list of the given linked list. But the problem with this approach is that i lose the original linked list. So I make another fucntion called `createReversedLinkedList` to make a `copy of the original linked list` and `reverse the copy` and maintain possession of both.
unfortunately `createReversedLinkedList` is giving `Runtime error`. 
obviously my end goal is to check `if the given linked list is palindrome or not`. This issue is just a stepping stone.
Could someone tell me why?

```
//Check if a linked list is a palindrome
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};

node *returnReverseLinkedList(node *head)
{
    // Will Lose original Linked List
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (head != NULL && head->next == NULL)
        return head;

    node *prev = NULL;
    node *curr = head;
    node *tempNext = head->next;

    while (tempNext != NULL)
    {
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = tempNext;
        tempNext = tempNext->next;
    }

    curr->next = prev;
    return curr;
}
node *createReversedLinkedList(node *head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (head != NULL && head->next == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        node *temp = head;

        node *newHead = NULL;
        node *newTail = NULL;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            node *newNode = new node(temp->data);
            if (newHead == NULL)
            {
                newHead = newNode;
                newTail = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                newTail->next = newNode;
                newTail = newNode;
            }
        }
        return returnReverseLinkedList(newHead);
    }
}

bool check_palindrome(node *head)
{
    node *original = head;
    node *reverse = returnReverseLinkedList(head);

    while (original->next != NULL || reverse->next != NULL)
    {
        if (original->data != reverse->data)
            return false;
        cout << "debug 2" << endl;
        original = original->next;
        reverse = reverse->next;
    }

    return true;
}
// #include "solution.h"
node *takeinput()
{
    int data;
    cin >> data;
    node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
    while (data != -1)
    {
        node *newnode = new node(data);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        }
        cin >> data;
    }
    return head;
}
void print(node *head)
{
    node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    node *head = takeinput();
    node *revese2 = createReversedLinkedList(head);
    print(revese2);
    // bool ans = check_palindrome(head);
    // if (ans)
    //     cout << "true";
    // else
    //     cout << "false";
    // return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) already exists.

Comment: You never change `temp`.  `while (temp != NULL)` is then always true, and your loop runs forever, or rather until running out of memory.

Comment: In addition to Igor's critical observation, `return NULL;` may be right in the opening case of a null head pointer, but it probably isn't right in the case of a single-node list, where a "reversal" is just the same node. As far as actually making a reversed-copy, traverse the original forward, and build the copy as you would a *stack* (e.g. push the copied forward-traversed nodes of the original list *backward* on the head of the new list). That also eliminates the need for a `returnReversedLinkdList` call entirely.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you please simply ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik totally solved the problem

Comment: @JesperJuhl Doing it without using STL

Comment: I think you can removed the 'recursion' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As asked by the OP, building a reversed linked is simply done by building as you would a *stack* (e.g LIFO) rather than duplicating the same original forward chain. For example:

```
node *createReversedLinkedList(const node *head)
{
    node *newHead = NULL;
    for (; head; head = head->next)
    {
        node *p = new node(head->data)
        p->next = newHead;
        newHead = p;
    }
    return newHead;
}
```

Note we're not hanging our copied nodes on the *tail* of the new list; they're hanging on the head of the new list, and becoming the new head with each addition. That's it. There is no need to craft an identical list, then reverse it; you can reverse it while building the copy to begin with.

---

A note on the remainder of your code. You have a *dreadful* memory leak, even if you fix the reversal generation as I've shown above. In your `check_palindrome` function, you never free the dynamic reversed copy (and in fact, you can't because you discard the original pointer referring to its head after the first traversal:

```
bool check_palindrome(node *head)
{
    node *original = head;
    node *reverse = returnReverseLinkedList(head); // only reference to reversed copy

    while (original->next != NULL || reverse->next != NULL)
    {
        if (original->data != reverse->data)
            return false; // completely leaked entire reversed copy
        original = original->next;
        reverse = reverse->next; // lost original list head
    }

    return true;
}
```

The most obvious method for combating that dreadful leak is to remember the original list and use a different pointer to iterate, and don't leave the function until the copy is freed.

```
bool check_palindrome(const node *head)
{
    bool result = true;
    node *reverse = returnReverseLinkedList(head);

    for (node *p = reverse; p; p = p->next, head = head->next)
    {
        if (p->data != head->data)
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    while (reverse)
    {
        node *tmp = reverse;
        reverse = reverse->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    return result;
}
```